# Django display name of foreign key instead of foreign key id

Tags: django

How do I display the name of a foreign key from a query?

```
class Books (models.Models)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)

class Category(models.Models)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def list_books_totalamount_by_category(request):
  context = Books.objects.filter(user=4).values('category').annotate(amount2=Sum('amount'))
  return render(request, 'test.html', {'context':context}
```

How do I make the query display the category name instead of the category_id?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Books.objects.filter(user=4).values('category__name').annotate(amount2=Sum('amount'))
```